# Is it possible to use Windows 8 with a keyboard that lacks a start key?

Tags: windows-8, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I have found an old AT-era keyboard that lacks the Windows 95 “start” and “app” keys. It has a great click mechanism and that is the reason I would like to use it. The problem is to operate Windows 8 with only a keyboard several start-key shortcuts (such as <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) are seemingly required. Are there any alternatives to these? (Windows Vista and earlier could be fully operated without the start key.)

Comment: Someone has discovered *buckling-spring mechanical keyboards* :) You could always just get [one with the meta key](http://pckeyboard.com/page/UKBD/UB40P4A).

Comment: @DarthAndroid They’re expensive as hell, that’s why I would rather use the one I just found in my basement.

Comment: The best way to remap a key using Autohotkey.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> is an alternative for Windows key, but it does not work for shortcuts such as <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (make all windows collapsed).
You can also remap windows key to any other key on keyboard (right <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for example) with the utility [Sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)